# Check my SQL connection every second without freezing

Tags: c#, .net, task

First of all, I apologize for my English.

I have a method to verify my connection to SQL (`TestConneccion`), and I use a timer to verify it every second.

The problem is when I lose the connection, my application hangs while it tries to connect. I'm using task to avoid this, but I am new to C#.

I would really appreciate the help

```
    public string testConeccion()
    {
        var archivo = "";

        try
        {
            odb = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("TESTCONECTION");
            ocn = odb.CreateConnection();

            if (ocn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) 
            {
                ocn.Open();  
            }

            ocn.Close();
            archivo = "true";
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
        {
            archivo = ex.Message;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            archivo = ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            ocn.Close();
        }

        return archivo;
    }

    private void timerMesas_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task<string> T1 = Task.Run<string>(() => oClasePublica.testConeccion());

        if (T1.Result == "true")
        {
            btnEstado.Image = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(TOUCHREST.Properties.Resources.Status_32x32);
        }
        else
        {
            btnEstado.Image = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(TOUCHREST.Properties.Resources.Warning_32x32);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show code for TestConexion

Comment: im sorry, it is not TestConexion, it is TestConeccion().

Comment: You seem to be missing a `using` statement, cause I assume your connection implements `IDisposable`? Also, you seem to close it twice, (in case the connection succeeds) as the finally block will always be executed

Comment: This is not a good idea.  You need put your data access on a separate thread so your UI stays active.  If the connection fails on the separate thread then notify the user.  Opening and Closes connection is expensive and you should NEVER do this.  If you want to check a connection, use a TcpClient and try to connect to the port the server is on.

Comment: @ErikPhilips, i have been told to use backgroundworker. when you say expensive, you mean : spending less resources?.

Comment: Yeah a background worker with TcpClient would be very optimal.  [Connection Pooling - Connecting to a database server typically consists of several time-consuming steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling).

Answer (score 0):

Make your timer tick handler `async` and `await` your task. This will run the method asynchronously and prevent the rest of your application from hanging while it runs.

```
private async void timerMesas_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string T1 = await Task.Run<string>(() => oClasePublica.testConeccion());
    if (T1 == "true")
    {
        btnEstado.Image = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(TOUCHREST.Properties.Resources.Status_32x32);
    }
    else
    {
        btnEstado.Image = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(TOUCHREST.Properties.Resources.Warning_32x32);
    }
}
```

Comment: i still have the problem, it freeze when i lose connection  with sql.

Comment: This doesn't work because it uses await.  The Task.Run should not use await, but instead should have a `ContinueWith()` that sets the image.

Answer (score 0):

The `ocn.Close()` in the `try` code is not needed because the `finally` will do it. Also `catch (InvalidOperationException ex)` is not needed because `catch (Exception)` covers it.

You cannot do `Task.Run` and then immediately test the `Result` because the task has not yet finished!  Normally you use `Task.Wait()`; however this will then block your main thread.

I suggest using a [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) that continuously checks the connection and then reports it progress.  This avoids the issue of changing the image on a non-UI thread.

Comment: i will seek information about BackgroundWorker, thansk a lot.

Comment: @RichardSchneider, i have been told to use tcpclient and not opening and closing connection, because is expensive.
you agree?

Comment: Yes opening a connection (either tcp or sql) every second is expensive.  Why do this at all.  Just handle the exception when trying to perform a SQL operation.